# Hover multiple elements at once, backwards compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set up a scrambled looking navigation menu.  Words are split up, but when you hover over one word, the corresponding words all change to a different color, thus revealing the method to the madness.  I was able to accomplish this in one direction with html/css, but css is "cascading" I cannot get it to work in reverse.  Here is an example of what I am looking for:

Example links would be -

Red Square
Blue Circle
Green Triangle

I want the menu to look scrambled, like this -

Red Blue Square Green Circle Triangle

Hovering over "Red" OR "Square" changes both of those links a different color
Hovering over "Blue" OR "Circle" changes them, etc...

So my menu html would look something like -

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="/link1" class="one">Red</a></li>
<li><a href="/link2" class="two">Blue</a></li>
<li><a href="/link1" class="one">Square</a></li>
<li><a href="/link3" class="three">Green</a></li>
<li><a href="/link2" class="two">Circle</a></li>
<li><a href="/link3" class="three">Triangle</a></li>
</ul>
```

I think this can probably be accomplished pretty easily with jquery, but need a little help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/cofr7498/

```js
$(".one").mouseover(function(){
  $(".one").css("color", "red");
});
$(".one").mouseout(function(){
  $(".one").css("color", "blue");
});
$(".two").mouseover(function(){
  $(".two").css("color", "red");
});
$(".two").mouseout(function(){
  $(".two").css("color", "blue");
});
$(".three").mouseover(function(){
  $(".three").css("color", "red");
});
$(".three").mouseout(function(){
  $(".three").css("color", "blue");
});
```

```css
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/link1" class="one">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2" class="two">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link1" class="one">Square</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link3" class="three">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2" class="two">Circle</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link3" class="three">Triangle</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That does seem to be exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really easy way, using the `addEventListener` and the `mouseover` event

It sets the hovered elements class to the `ul`, and then one simply pair the classes `ul.one .one`

```js
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  this.className = e.target.className;
})
```

```css
ul.one .one {
  color: red;
}
ul.two .two {
  color: yellow;
}
ul.three .three {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/link1" class="one">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2" class="two">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link1" class="one">Square</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link3" class="three">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2" class="two">Circle</a></li>
  <li><a href="/link3" class="three">Triangle</a></li>
</ul>
```